# Do different Windows users / profiles have different certificate stores?

Tags: windows-10, security, ssl, certificate

I was considering setting up different "trusted environments" where various entities I have to access have their own trusted self-signed certificates in the operating system.  For environment A, I might want to set it up as a client for company 1 (trusting a self-signed certificate issued by 1), environment B might want to be a client for company 2 (trusting a self-signed certificate for company 2), and so on.  Today I only have two such "companies" I would need to trust this way.

I'm not worried about complexity of the setup as I only have like one or two companies on one or two machines, so maybe 4 total environments to set up and maintain.

My initial idea: set up different "users" for the Windows system.  Then I have like a "company 1" environment, a "company 2" environment, and then a "personal" environment.

Questions, then:

1. **Do different user profiles in Windows 10 have different trusted certificate databases?**  If I trust a self-signed cert to sign other certs for user A in Windows, will it trust certs when user B is logged in?
2. **Is there another obvious way to do this?**  The only other obvious one I could think of were virtual machines, but I need to typically use A/V equipment in the nested setups and that was going poorly. It also costs me a bunch of money in Windows licenses, which I didn't really want to do if I didn't have to.

Comment: There is a certificate store per user and a certificate store per computer. A certificate in the computer's store can be shared amongst all users, whereas one in a user's store is purely for that user.